# Deploy a Mailjet Email Service through Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, mailjet

I need to create a Mailjet Email Service on Azure, through Azure CLI, but I haven't found any documentation on how to achieve this. I know there isn't a built-in `az` command to deploy such service, but I wonder if there is a workaround, and thus a way to deploy a Mailjet Email Service by leveraging Azure CLI?

If yes, can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in [Az commands references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest) and [extension references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/account/?view=azure-cli-latest) to deploy a Mailjet Email Service through Azure CLI. Azure CLI is a set of commands used to create and manage Azure resources. It is available across Azure services.

In addition, as a workaround, perhaps, you're interested. But I have not tried it as it looks more complex and less easy than [enabling Mailjet through Azure portal](https://www.mailjet.com/guides/azure-mailjet-developer-resource-user-guide/enabling-mailjet). In this way, you could catch the API via clicking F12 in the browser when you clicking the `create` button to enable Mailjet in the Azure portal, then use [az rest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest) to invoke a custom request referring to the caught API in the previous step. See [this blog](https://www.codeisahighway.com/native-azure-rest-api-calls-now-available-in-azure-cli-2-0-67/) and [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) for more references.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, I'll def. have a look at that. and btw, I think your second link is pointing to the wrong location

Comment: Do you see "extension references" on the left tab of the linked page? I mean you can see that az supported commands there.

Comment: If there is no else better method for this question, you may consider accepting this reply.:)

Comment: sure, I will. But let me do some more research first